# How to use access_token to authenticate SPA with Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, access-token

I'm trying to authenticate my single page app (written in Marionette) with my Laravel 5.4 app. In my previous experience, an SPA would:

- send the username & password to an `/api/login-token` endpoint which would return with something like the following:

  `{
  "access_token":"-wt7x8UPRH9GcbTeUQ3wIA7zuc02XeHil4qsoKJcOUU",
  "type":"Bearer",
  "expires_in":2570,
  "refresh_token":"g9zmNkC1zpQ8fM0uSeJdy_VZe7TuBUG4MYGIBuAtXvg"
  }`
- the SPA will store the `access_token` in the browser's localstorage, and send it in an `access_token` header with every subsequent request made to the backend
- the backend will recognise this `access_token` and authenticate the user

**Unfortunately I'm struggling to understand how to achieve this in Laravel 5.4.**

Do I need to use Passport? I really don't think I need OAuth2, but does Passport also offer simple token-based auth? It seems to, and I have gotten the expected tokens described above from the `/oauth/token` endpoint, but I don't know how to use this token. I don't think it's even for this purpose.

I tried sending a request to `/api/user` with this token in the headers, POSTing it, and as a query string, with no luck. Also making me concerned is the `expires_in` from Laravel is a *year* (31536000 seconds = 365 days)  which seems way too long. I'm worried this Passport OAuth token is actually for OAuth2 access and not a 1-day-ish expiring access token that I'm used to.

I also read about Laravel's `TokenGuard` but that seems like some weird kind of token that's stored in an `api_token` column on the `user` table, which is all wrong by my mindset. For example, it doesn't expire, and it's per-user not per-user-session, meaning the same token would have to be used from multiple devices. etc

Very confused... grateful for any help!

Comment: have you checked out authentication with JWT too? Maybe this tutorial can inspire you a bit https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

Comment: Looks like JWT is indeed my answer. As a Laravel beginner it's hard to know what's included and what's not. Thanks for the suggestion! Feel free to make this an answer and I'll accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using Passport, based on some really helpful code found at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/api-authentication-with-passport?page=1&replyId=282168:

routes/api.php

```php
Route::post('auth/token', 'Api\Auth\DefaultController@authenticate');
Route::post('auth/refresh', 'Api\Auth\DefaultController@refreshToken');
```

app/Http/Controllers/Api/Auth/DefaultController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var object
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * DefaultController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', 2)->first();
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $request->request->add([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
            'scope' => '*'
        ]);

        $proxy = Request::create(
            'oauth/token',
            'POST'
        );

        return Route::dispatch($proxy);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function refreshToken(Request $request)
    {
        $request->request->add([
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' => $request->refresh_token,
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
        ]);

        $proxy = Request::create(
            '/oauth/token',
            'POST'
        );

        return Route::dispatch($proxy);
    }
}
```

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

You may try JWT and this tutorial might be an inspiration for you:  https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps